# Cannot use PowerPoint 2010 with Slide Library

Tags: 2010, office-integration, slidelibrary

I am trying to use PowerPoint 2010 with a slide library. When I click Upload > Publish Slides within the slide library, I get the error "This feature requires Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007. Either the application is not installed, or your browser is not configured to support ActiveX controls." I have Office Professional Plus 2010 - is it really not compatible?? I tried temporarily enabling all the ActiveX settings to no avail. It works if I install Office Pro Plus 2007, but the users have 2010. I am able to publish from PowerPoint to SharePoint (Save & Send > Publish Slides) using the library URL, and I can also drag and drop files using Windows Explorer, but ideally we would like the Upload > Publish Slides feature to work from within the library. Any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your site a trusted site? If so, have you tried to reset the security settings to the default zones in IE? Does your installation include the SharePoint Support?

Comment: I am having the same problem with a SharePoint 2010 slide library and Office 2013. My SharePoint site is trusted and is on the intranet zone. Does anyone have anything else I can try? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We were having some trouble with Office (Excel, Word, etc) integration too and narrowed it down the the 64-bit version of IE9.  The ActiveX controls used for Office integration are not fully supported for the 64-bit versions of IE.  Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit versions of your browser?

The arcticle below says that Microsoft Office 2010 does not provide a 64-bit version of the Slide library and PowerPoint 2010 integration control.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx